# in Filament v3.x how to show city Name when city ID is saved in the table

Tags: laravel-filament, filamentphp

I am new to the filament. in the below code I need to show the city name, but because in the table, we have stored just the city ID. Now I can query the city table with the city_id to fetch the city name, but i am not sure how to show that.

```
public static function table(Table $table): Table
{
    return $table
        ->columns([
            Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('city_id')
            ->searchable()
            ->sortable(),
```

I did not used the relationships to get the city data. here is the code in the forms to get the city ID

```
                                Forms\Components\Select::make('city_id')
                            ->options(fn (Get $get): Collection => City::query()
                                ->where('state_id', $get('state_id'))
                                ->pluck('name', 'id'))
                                ->searchable()
                                ->preload(),
```

Answer (score 0):

create a relation in the model and call it city like so:

```
public function city(){
return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
}
```

then in filament column

```
Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('city.name')
        ->searchable()
        ->sortable()
```

Answer (score 0):

Import your model:

```
use App\Models\City;
```

For the table

```
 Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('city_id')
 ->searchable()
 ->formatStateUsing(fn (string $state, City $city): string => __("#$city->id 
 $city->name"))
 ->sortable(),
```

For the Form

```
Forms\Components\Select::make('city_id')
->getOptionLabelFromRecordUsing(fn (City $city) => "#{$city->id} -{$city->name}")
->searchable()
->preload(),
```

And don't forget to add to your model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use App\Models\City;

    public function city(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
    }
```